Awaited<R> is not being unwrapped to R with response object
I'm returning an AxiosResponse object from a call to axios.get in a generic function. That object has the shape:
interface AxiosResponse<T = any, D = any> {
  data: T;
  ...
}

The get call has this type:
get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>): Promise<R>;

I'm hours into digging for an answer to fix this error:
"Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Awaited<R>

In this code (error location marked):
export const fetchWithRetry = async <
  T = any,
  Q = Record<string, string>,
  R = AxiosResponse<T>
>(
  route: string,
  queryParams: Partial<Q> = {},
) => {
  const response = await fetchResponseWithRetry<T, Q, R>(route, queryParams)
  return response.data; // <= ERROR IS HERE
};

export const fetchResponseWithRetry = async <
  T = any,
  Q = Record<string, string>,
  R = AxiosResponse<T>,
>(
  route: string,
  queryParams: Partial<Q> = {},
) => {
  try {
    const options: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      params: <Q>{ ...queryParams },
    };
    return (await axios.get<T, R, unknown>(route, options));
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      buildLogger(`${error.message}`);
      if (error instanceof AxiosError) buildLogger(`${error.request.url}`);
    }
  }
  throw new Error(`This should never be reached.`);
};

I understand that the Awaited<R> type was added in 4.5. I understand from other answers that the Awaited type should be unwrapped to R (from the accepted answer on that question):

If the type T you are awaiting is a Promise<U> where U isn't a Promise of any kind, then Awaited<T> is the same as U

How do I fix this?

The problem here is that you're customisation of the R type means the response could literally be anything so Typescript cannot guarantee it has a data property.
There's really no need to provide generics for anything other than the T response data type.
This code works without any errors and also does away with a few other small issues
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
export const fetchWithRetry = async <T = any,>(
  route: string,
  queryParams: Record<string, string> = {},
) => {
  const response = await fetchResponseWithRetry<T>(route, queryParams);
  return response.data;
};

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
export const fetchResponseWithRetry = async <T = any,>(
  route: string,
  queryParams: Record<string, string> = {},
) => {
  try {
    // GET requests do not have a body so no content-type required
    const options: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      params: queryParams,
    };
    return await axios.get<T>(route, options);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      buildLogger(`${error.message}`);
      if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
        // use the provided type guard method
        buildLogger(`${error.request.url}`);
      }
    }
  }
  throw new Error(`This should never be reached.`);
};

If you really wanted to keep the R generic, you should use extends instead of a default value.
R extends { data: T } = AxiosResponse<T>


Thank you @Phil. My brain is a little scrambled - I'll try this tomorrow. Thank you for your answer. I'll accept it after I have a chance to try it.

@webstackdev you're welcome. FYI you might want to keep your Q generic but I thought it was pretty redundant. Axios' params accepts any and can do some funky stuff with objects and arrays

That's a good point on Q. What I'm really trying to achieve is to have typing on the response.

and thank you for your modding on this question. I've had really, really, really bad experiences with the last few questions I've asked on SO. I've had an account with SO for seven years or so. I wrote this post on Reddit and swore I'd never come back. It's been a year (and several since my last question), and I thought I'd try.

@webstackdev no worries. This is a good question to have on the site and thanks for being positively responsive to the initial feedback

thank you again for your answer and modding. One quick question: I haven't see this syntax before on the second line. It doesn't error; would you help me understand what it is?   <T = any,>

and also, I understand now why adding the R type parameter in the second function caused my problem, but why did it change the type to Promise< AxiosResponse | undefined>  instead of Promise< AxiosResponse | unknown> (the wrapped value of Awaited)? I didn't include that in my original question, but that was the type I saw on hover in VS Code.

@webstackdev the trailing comma is just Prettier doing its thing (makes for cleaner diffs when adding more generics). The issue with R = Something is basically saying that R is any but defaults to Something if not otherwise specified. If you want to use R within the same function, you need it to have stronger typing

The solution here is to do a type assertion. If you refactor the functions as follows:
export async function fetchWithRetry<
    T = any,
    Q = Record<string, string>,
    R = AxiosResponse<T>,
>(route: string, queryParams: Partial<Q> = {}) {
    const response = await fetchResponseWithRetry<T, Q, R>(route, queryParams);
    const data = response.data;
    return data;
}

export async function fetchResponseWithRetry<
    T = any,
    Q = Record<string, string>,
    R = AxiosResponse<T>,
>(route: string, queryParams: Partial<Q> = {}) {
    try {
        const options: AxiosRequestConfig = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            params: <Q>{ ...queryParams },
        };
        return (await axios.get<T, R, unknown>("/url", options)) as Promise<{
            data: R;
        }>;
    } catch (e) {
        if ((e as AxiosError).response?.status === 429) {
            throw e;
        }
        throw e;
    }
}

You can adjust this to fit your needs such that you can access the particular fields in AxiosResponse as you see fit.

I upvoted so that your answer is even keel, Omar. I think the reason you got the downvote is because assertions really aren't solving the problem - they're just opting out of the type system.

I appreciate the feedback. I’ll keep that in mind! The other answer is certainly more elegant.
